# Angular native debounce with $timeout vs lodash_.debounce benchmark

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

Wanted to test which method would be faster, debounce function that uses native angular `$timeout`, or lodash built in `_.debounce()` function.

So I have created benchmark, and wanted to ask, can this benchmark be considered as objective, and if not, what should be changed so that test would be equal for both functions?

https://jsfiddle.net/ues8d4pL/

To test with $timeout, line
`debounceUpdate({ value: i }, $scope.model);` is used.

To test lodash function

```
// 2. Test With lodash
// _.debounce(function() {
//     saveParameters({ value: i }, $scope.model);
// }, 1000)();
```

lines should be uncommented. For me it took 2585.61msecs with $timeout, and 4240.875msecs with lodash.

Can this benchmark be considered as correct and if not what I need to change?

Also which way would be more preferable, using native $timeout or lodash debounce?

Comment: Why would you rebuild the wheel?

Comment: Calling `_.debounce(…, …)()` does not debounce anything - it just calls the function once.

Comment: @Bergi can you correct my code so it would be equal with $timeout approach ?

Comment: You have to do `var debounced = _.debounce(…, …)`, then repeatedly (asynchronously?) loop `for(…){ debounced() }`

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve but angular has native model debounce functionality (especially useful with forms) with [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benchmark is being performed the wrong way.

```
_.debounce(function() {
    saveParameters({ value: i }, $scope.model);
}, 1000)();
```

creates a new debounced function on each iteration and calls it instantly, it is similar to doing `setTimeout` on each iteration and doesn't have any debouncing effect. The reason why unthrottled function is relatively light on CPU is because it doesn't do `$rootScope.$apply()` (like `$timeout`).

The proper use for `_.debounce` that can be directly compared with `$timeout` debounce is

```
var lodashDebounceUpdate = _.debounce(function() {
    $timeout(function () {
        saveParameters({ value: i }, $scope.model);
    });
}, 1000);

for (...) {
    lodashDebounceUpdate();
}
```

There's nothing really 'native' in `$timeout`, it just [wraps `setTimeout` under the hood](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/ng/browser.js#L319) in the way in which it can perform synchronously in specs.

In earlier Underscore/Lodash implementations `_.debounce` uses `setTimeout` in similar intuitive manner.

In modern versions both [Underscore](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.8.3/underscore.js#L837) and [Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/f7c4410f41030ca9eab4794573f8f5a67662c211/lodash.js#L9605) have switched to implementation that makes use of `Date.now()` and is ~50000x faster (the measurement is based on private in vitro benchmarks).

So yes, `_.debounce` is more performant than custom `$timeout`/`setTimeout`-based debouncing function, it can be beneficial if debounced function expects hundreds of calls per second. Otherwise this may be considered premature optimization.